# Change value for specific row in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've got a matrix in Matlab that looks something like this;

```
A = 
   1    2    3    4
   5    7    8    9
  10   11   12   13
```

How can I change the matrix so that the entrie first row is set to a specific value? So that it becomes this;

```
A = 
   2    2    2    2
   5    7    8    9
  10   11   12   13
```

Comment: I've googled,and looked in the Matlab doc's for quite some time, but did not find the answer there. You shouldn't discourage people from using StackOverflow. If the question bothered you,then you could have just moved along. For me it was an important question I couldn't find the answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it is the obvious

```
A(1,:) = 2
```